# How to write an inline IF statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

How can I use an inline `if` statement in JavaScript? Is there an inline `else` statement too?

Something like this:

```
var a = 2;
var b = 3;

if(a < b) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Where's the jQuery here? And I don't really understand the question anyway.

Comment: jquery part might be like this $(document).ready(function(){    


var a = 2;
var b = 3;

if(a < b) {
    // do something
}

});

Comment: its a knockoutjs question too

Comment: It's also an angular 1 and 2 and every other js framework (including vanilla.js) out there question

Answer (score 835, accepted):

You don't necessarily need jQuery.  JavaScript alone will do this.

```
var a = 2;
var b = 3;    
var c = ((a < b) ? 'minor' : 'major');
```

The `c` variable will be `minor` if the value is `true`, and `major` if the value is `false`.

---

This is known as a  Conditional (ternary) Operator.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: It illustrates how to use an Inline IF, which answers the question EXACTLY.

Comment: Just to note, all parens in this case are optional. It is often personal preference/coding style that dictates when they are used.

Comment: @WillKlein you say all parens are optional yet when I do this as ()?: instead of (()?:) I get different results. I only know this because I tried it like it is in PHP.

Comment: @khany, this is a JavaScript question. Expressions may evaluate in other languages differently.

Comment: @MattW This doesn't show how to use an Inline IF, it shows how to use an IF ELSE

Comment: @MattW is there a way to use the ternary if without else ?

Comment: @getName not really, but you could use a one line if statement if you wanted `if (a < b) c = 'major';`

Comment: Ah, yes, the null coalescing operator, and the joys of being multi-lingual.

Answer (score 63):

There is a ternary operator, like this:

```
var c = (a < b) ? "a is less than b"  : "a is not less than b";
```

Comment: It doesn't actually have to be assigned to anything.  The right hand side elements can simply be function calls.

Comment: They don't even have to be function calls... `0 < 1 : 5 : 120;` is a perfectly valid statement. A little useless unless you're paid per line, though.

Comment: @jfriend00 I would advise against it in almost all cases, though. If you're not using the value of the expression, then what you really want is side effects; and side effects is what *statements* are great for. Using the plain old boring `if` statement in such a case will probably make your code much easier to read and understand, and less likely to break with later changes.

Answer (score 56):

For writing `if` statement inline, the code inside of it should only be one statement:

```
if ( a < b ) // code to be executed without curly braces;
```

Answer (score 47):

You can also approximate an if/else using only Logical Operators.

```
(a && b) || c
```

The above is roughly the same as saying:

```
a ? b : c
```

And of course, roughly the same as:

```
if ( a ) { b } else { c }
```

I say roughly because there is one difference with this approach, in that you have to know that the value of `b` will evaluate as true, otherwise you will always get `c`. Bascially you have to realise that the part that would appear `if () { here }` is now part of the condition that you place `if ( here ) {  }`.

The above is possible due to JavaScripts behaviour of passing / returning one of the original values that formed the logical expression, which one depends on the type of operator. Certain other languages, like PHP, carry on the actual result of the operation i.e. true or false, meaning the result is always true or false; e.g:

```
14 && 0          /// results as 0,  not false
14 || 0          /// results as 14, not true
1 && 2 && 3 && 4 /// results as 4,  not true
true && ''       /// results as ''
{} || '0'        /// results as {}
```

One main benefit, compared with a normal if statement, is that the first two methods can operate on the righthand-side of an argument i.e. as part of an assignment.

```
d = (a && b) || c;
d = a ? b : c;

if `a == true` then `d = b` else `d = c`
```

The only way to achieve this with a standard if statement would be to duplicate the assigment:

```
if ( a ) { d = b } else { d = c }
```

You may ask why use just [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators) instead of the [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#conditional_operator), for simple cases you probably wouldn't, unless you wanted to make sure `a` and `b` were both true. You can also achieve more streamlined complex conditions with the Logical operators, which can get quite messy using nested ternary operations... then again if you want your code to be easily readable, neither are really that intuative.

Answer (score 37):

In plain English, the syntax explained:

```
if(condition){
    do_something_if_condition_is_met;
}
else{
    do_something_else_if_condition_is_not_met;
}
```

Can be written as:

```
condition ? do_something_if_condition_is_met : do_something_else_if_condition_is_not_met;
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without the "else" statement?  ie `condition ? true`

Comment: @ScottBeeson Sure. It also depends on your usage of the condition. `true` `false` and `""` should all be fine to ignore the else portion.

Comment: So `2 == 2 ? doSomething()` would be the same as `if (2 == 2) doSomething()`?

Comment: Yes, but the else part cannot be completely omitted. At lease `: false` or `: ""` should be there as javascript is expecting this.

Comment: Oh. So it's *not* possible to do it without the else statement.

Answer (score 27):

If you just want an inline IF (without the ELSE), you can use the logical AND operator:

```
(a < b) && /*your code*/;
```

If you need an ELSE also, use the ternary operation that the other people suggested.

Answer (score 22):

You could do like this in JavaScript:

```
a < b ? passed() : failed();
```

Answer (score 22):

```
<div id="ABLAHALAHOO">8008</div>
<div id="WABOOLAWADO">1110</div>

parseInt( $( '#ABLAHALAHOO' ).text()) > parseInt( $( '#WABOOLAWADO ).text()) ? alert( 'Eat potato' ) : alert( 'You starve' );
```

Comment: I don't even know what I just read, but I'm laughing pretty hard.

Answer (score 9):

I often need to run more code per condition, by using: `( , , )` multiple code elements can execute:

```
var a = 2;
var b = 3;
var c = 0;

( a < b ?  ( alert('hi'), a=3, b=2, c=a*b ) : ( alert('by'), a=4, b=10, c=a/b ) );
```

Answer (score 8):

FYI, you can compose [conditional operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
var a = (truthy) ? 1 : (falsy) ? 2 : 3;
```

If your logic is sufficiently complex, then you might consider using an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

```
var a = (function () {
  if (truthy) return 1;
  else if (falsy) return 2;
  return 3;
})();
```

Of course, if you plan to use this logic more than once, then you aught to encapsulate it in a function to keep things nice and DRY.

Answer (score 6):

inline if:

```
(('hypothesis') ? 'truthy conclusion' : 'falsey conclusion')
```

truthy conclusion: statements executed when hypothesis is true

falsey conclusion: statements executed when hypothesis is false

your example:

```
var c = ((a < b) ? 'a<b statements' : '!(a<b) statements');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Ternary operator which equates to a simple if, else.

Ternary operation which calls functions for both outcomes:

```
(a < b) ? DoSomething() : DoSomethingElse();
```

Ternary operation which calls a function for only one of the outcomes:

```
(a < b) ? DoSomething() : {}; or (a < b)?.DoSomething();
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to this you can also use inline if condition with && and || operators.
Like this

```
var a = 2;
var b = 0;

var c = (a > b || b == 0)? "do something" : "do something else";
```

Answer (score 2):

Inline `if` in JavaScript is simple and requires no braces:

```js
if (a < b) doSomething()
```

Technically you can have an `else` in the same line, but it requires a semicolon:

```js
if (a < b) doSomething(); else doSomethingElse()
```

The above examples may not be desired by your team's coding standards. The most important thing is that you follow conventions that work for your team. Personally, I prefer `if` statements over ternaries in many cases because I find them easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the question essentially: can I write the following?

```
if (foo)
  console.log(bar)
else
  console.log(foo + bar)
```

the answer is, yes, the above will translate.

however, be wary of doing the following

```
if (foo)
  if (bar)
    console.log(foo)
  else 
    console.log(bar)
else 
  console.log(foobar)
```

be sure to wrap ambiguous code in braces as the above will throw an exception (and similar permutations will produce undesired behaviour.)

Answer (score 1):

Simplify ternary operator

```
var locked = 1;
var canChange = locked != 1 ? true : false;
```

If the locked is 1, then the `canChange` variable is set to `false`, otherwise, it is set to true.
In this case, you can simplify it by using a Boolean expression as follows:

```
var locked = 1;
var canChange = locked != 1;
```

For multiple JavaScript ternary operators
The following example shows how to use two ternary operators in the same expression:

```
var speed = 90;
var message = speed >= 120 ? 'Too Fast' : (speed >= 80 ? 'Fast' : 'OK');
console.log(message);
```

It is a best practice to use the ternary operator when it makes the code easier to read. If the logic contains many if...else statements, you shouldn’t use the ternary operators.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody's used arrays:

```js
alert([prompt("falsey condition?"), prompt("truthy condition?")][BigInt(Boolean(2 == 1))]);
```