# Calculate price from quantity input box in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I'm having a small issue calculating price from Quantity in jQuery. Those are the input boxes i have.

```
Quantity: <input type="text" style="width: 50px;" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="txt" value="1" />

Price: <input type="text" style="width: 50px;" name="item_price" id="item_price" class="txt" value="2990" />

Total Price: <input type="text" style="width: 50px;" name="total_price" id="total_price" class="txt" value="" />
```

Comment: None. Unless you explain what you want to achieve. Should it be based from the user input? from the hardcoded value in your input fields? Should that happen when page is loaded? On the fly? ...

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you want the formulae or how to get the values of the input elements:

```
var quantity = $("#quantity").val();
var iPrice = $("#item_price").val();

var total = quantity * iPrice;

$("#total_price").val(total); // sets the total price input to the quantity * price

alert(total);
```

**Edit for Keyup**:

```
$('#quantity').keyup(function() {
   var quantity = $("#quantity").val();
   var iPrice = $("#item_price").val();

   var total = quantity * iPrice;

   $("#total_price").val(total); // sets the total price input to the quantity * price
});
```

Comment: This works but no live/keyup when i change the quantity, any idea ?

Comment: @HafsteinnMárMásson included a keyup example for when quantity is changed. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but now the price won't appear unless i make a change in the quantity field, any quick fix for that ?

Comment: @HafsteinnMárMásson the price should appear on page load.  Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/WXyNw/

Comment: @HafsteinnMárMásson if you wanted it to change live when the price is changed you need an event handler to handle this too, you could copy the keyup function I created for you and change "#quantity" to "#item_price"

Answer (score 2):

> ***updated*** to show full example in script tags

If you want the formula and how you can "see" the change:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {  //  In jQuery 1.6+ this is same as $(document).ready(function(){})
        $('#quantity, #item_price')  //  jQuery CSS selector grabs elements with the ID's "quantity" & "item_price"
            .on('change', function(e) {  //  jQuery 1.6+ replcement for .live (dynamically asigns event, see jQuery API)
            //  in this case, our event is "change" which works on inputs and selects to let us know when a value is changed
                //  below i use inline if statements to assure the values i get are "Real"
                var quan = $("#quantity").val() != "" ? parseFloat($("#quantity").val()) : 1,  //  Get quantity value
                    pric = $("#item_price").val() != "" ? parseFloat($("#item_price").val()) : 0;  //  Get price value
                $('#total_price').val(pric*quan); // show total
            });
    });
</script>
```

- [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/)
- [jQuery API .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
- [jQuery API Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/change/)
- [jQuery API .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [jQuery API .live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [jQuery API .change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)
- [jQuery API .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)
- [inline if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270351/how-to-write-a-inline-if-statement-in-javascript)

Comment: This is how I'd do it. You need to add the above in a ``<Script type="text/javascript">`` just above your ``</body>`` section.. Just in case it is not obvious to OP

Comment: acutally this use of `.on` isn't the replacement for live.. you have to use the delegating version which is `$(staticparent).on('events','elements',function()`