# javascript can i put a variable check inside a string

Tags: javascript

is something like this possible in javascript?

maybe I have a variable (in this case its a number) that sometimes might be undefined. I'd like to sort of do some code right in the string to check the variable...

ps: I know that this throws throws an error!

```
var mystring='<b class="my string">'+(if(variable){variable;}else{0;})+'</b>';
```

Comment: Have you looked at [inline conditionals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270351/how-to-write-an-inline-if-statement-in-javascript)?

Comment: Yes, you can do this in JS as people have illustrated below, but just because you can do this doesn't mean you should. Inserting logic within a string nested in a scoped variable isn't good practice. If you decide to write unit tests or even debug your code it can become very difficult. I would recommend keeping your logic and string assignment separate.

Answer (score 2):

You can using the [conditional operator (`?:`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
var
    variable = true,
    mystring = 'Hello, ' + ( variable ? 'world' : 'nobody' ) + '!'
;
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/FNBSH/1/).

Answer (score 2):

It seems the ternary operator ? will be of some use for you :

```
var like = true;

var myString = 'some string i ' +  ( (like) ? 'really' : 'do not' ) + ' like' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `typeof` operator will ***specifically*** tell you if the variable is defined or not.

Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

e.g.

```
var mystring = 'The variable ' + (typeof variable !== 'undefined' ? 'exists' : 'doesn\'t exist');
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FlameTrap/AJfFk/1/

Answer (score 0):

`var mystring = '<b class="my string">' + ( typeof variable !== undefined ) ? 'variable' : 0 + '</b>';`