# Javascript: if-else statement in document.getElementById.innerHTML not working

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I am printing out values of a values-array in a div.
I have the following code which is working very well:

```
...
...
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "Value: " + values[i];

<div id="div">The Value will be displayed here.</div>
```

However some of the values in my values-array are negative, but I would like to only show positive numbers of the array. So if a number is negative, it should say **0** instead.

I tried the following but its not working:

```
...
...
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "Value: " + if (values[i] < 0) {0} else {values[i]};
```

Any clues or hints? I am new to javascript, help is appreciated.

Comment: `"Value: " + (values[i] < 0 ? 0 : values[i]);` FYI - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270351/how-to-write-an-inline-if-statement-in-javascript

Comment: That isn't how an `if/else` statement works in Javascript.

Comment: try `document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "Value: " + (values[i]<0)? 0:values[i];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also consider [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max):

```js
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "Value: " + Math.max(0, values[i]);
```

Answer (score 3):

use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), as:

```
var vals = (values[i] < 0 ) ? 0 : values[i];
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "Value: " + vals;
```

Answer (score 2):

`if` statements do not 'return' a value; they indicate a code execution path, as in:

```
if this happens
   do this
else
  do that
```

you want to concatenate the a value depending on a condition, in your case, the ternary operator fits nicely as they return a possible value given a condition

`var returnedValue = (condition)? value-if-true : value-if-false;`

In your case:

`var myValue = (values[i] < 0)? 0 : values[i];
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "Value: " + myValue;`

Or putting it all together:

`document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "Value: " + (values[i] < 0)? 0 : values[i];`