# Javascript :? operator

Tags: javascript, react-native, flowtype

I can't figure out what this does or even is. Would someone please be so kind to point me what to research?

```
circle: (null : ?{ setNativeProps(props: Object): void }),
```

It's part of a React Native example and is part of a React Native class definition. The outer parts are (abbreviated):

```
var NavigatorIOSExample = React.createClass({
...
circle: (null : ?{ setNativeProps(props: Object): void }),
...
});
```

I assume it's some tricky use of the ternary operator. An anonymous function. But?

Source: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10270383/3000589

Comment: @Quentin I don't think that's what OP is asking. `null : ? ...` isn't valid native JavaScript syntax, and certainly isn't covered in [that post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript).

Comment: Indeed. Looks like a ternary operator (which is what I answered first) but it's not. Weird... never seen this.

Comment: Not JavaScript. Might be some React-magic...

Comment: I cannot find it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigatorios.html) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/NavigatorIOSExample.js) so please give us a real source you found this row; I guess this is your invention otherwise

Comment: @simon: if you googled the line given, it's from the React documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html

Comment: Circle is assigned an anonymous function. It's prop is then assigned setNativeProps or void?

Comment: I think that the `?{}` syntax is definitely some kind of "React voodoo," *not* JavaScript. *Not* a ternary operator.

Comment: Someone posted an answer saying it were related to Flow's type checking, but a few minutes later the answer got deleted. Seems sensible, but I wasn't able to figure it out with the Flow docs myself.

Comment: I posted the answer before, but I then tested the code out in Flow itself and it threw a syntax error. It appears that was for an old version of Flow: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/6e6bd28f3ac1ab214dc6fb7d88d236f57197ad44

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The declaration is syntax from [Flow](http://flowtype.org/docs/five-simple-examples.html#_). It says that 'circle' is an object with a property that is a function  named 'setNativeProps':

```js
{ setNativeProps(props: Object): void }
```

It also says that circle [is nullable](http://flowtype.org/docs/nullable-types.html) (indicated by the preceding '?') and that the default value will be null until an object of the specified type has been assigned to it.

If you look further down the sample you can see how calling code checks that circle has been assigned before calling setNativeProps:

```js
this.circle && this.circle.setNativeProps({
    backgroundColor: CIRCLE_HIGHLIGHT_COLOR
});
```