# Can I put one-line instructions in function array?

Tags: javascript

I don't know if I'm clear, but what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
 ajaxUpdate= $.ajax({
                        url: "updateSheet.php",
                        type: "post",
                        data: {
                            'update': 1,
                            'id': $('#numbah'+numbah+'').attr("class"),
                            'x': if (x) x,
                            'y': if (y) y,
                            'title': if (title) title,
                            'content': if (content) content
                        }
                    });
```

is something like `'x': if (x) x,` correct? I can't risk running this part of code corrupted, because it can mess with my file.

Comment: No, as you'll notice if you open your developer console, that syntax is not correct. In JS, `if` is not an expression. JS does have a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) though, that'll let you do `x ? x : ""`. Or you can use a [logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) `x || ""`. In both cases a default value of `""` is provided. There's no way to elide the entire property inline.

Comment: Your code / problem has nothing to do with JSON. It seems you are confusing an object literal with JSON.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [How to write an inline IF statement in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10270351/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and do `x ? x : ''`. This says if `x` is truthy (in your case if it's set) then return `x` otherwise return the empty string.  So you could do something like this:

```
ajaxUpdate= $.ajax({
                    url: "updateSheet.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        'update': 1,
                        'id': $('#numbah'+numbah+'').attr("class"),
                        'x': x ? x : '',
                        'y': y ? y : '',
                        'title': title ? title : '',
                        'content': content ? content : ''
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a three-way-operator `?:` which you could use like so:

```
title: title ? title : '',
content: content ? content : ''
```

This sends an empty string, if the variable is empty or the content of it if not.

Alternatively, you can use the logical OR operator `||`:

```
title: title || ''
content: content || ''
```

It's a little shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ternary operator - info [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
ajaxUpdate= $.ajax({
                    url: "updateSheet.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        'update': 1,
                        'id': $('#numbah'+numbah+'').attr("class"),
                        'x': x == someValue ? x: '',
                        'y': y == someValue ? y: '',
                        'title': if (title) title,
                        'content': if (content) content
                    }
                });
```