# If...then in JSX for Javascript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I've been writing Coffeescript/CJSX and this is valid syntax:

```
<div>
   <input type={if @state.name == "Test" then "checkbox"}/>
</div>
```

How do I do the same for plain Javascript? There is no `if...then` clause and I don't think I can do inline `if` checks like I can in Coffee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the answer from [How to write an inline IF statement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270351/how-to-write-an-inline-if-statement-in-javascript)

You can use the syntax `10 < 11 ? do this : do that` where the `?` is the `then` and the `:` is the `else`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use logical operators:

`<input type={(state.name == "Test" && "checkbox") || "text"}>`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation

Comment: Sure, you _can_ do that, but why would you? This is also subtly different in behavior from `?:` and could lead to insidious bugs if you're not careful.

Comment: That's true. I mostly use it to render elements in JSX. I.e. `{state.isValid && <p>Valid!</p>}`. But i think you're right in this case that the ternary is correct.