# How to use javascript to change the current variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small html page, where if the user clicks on one of the buttons, it will change the day. I have a function where it says what day it is today, but I want the user to be able to press ">", which will change the day from today to the next day. And the previous day if you press "<". I am no fully sure on how I should proceed now.

```js
var date = new Date();
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = days[date.getDay()];

function next() {
  var date = new Date();
  var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = days[date.getDay()];

  if (btnNext.click) {
    days++;
    document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = days[date.getDay()];
  }
}

function prev() {
  var date = new Date();
  var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = days[date.getDay()];

  if (btnNext.click) {
    days--;
    document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = days[date.getDay()];
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click to change day</p>
<button type="button" name="btnPrev" onclick="next()"><</button>
<button type="button" name="btnNext" onclick="prev()">></button>
<p id="todayField"></p>
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: The term you're looking for is circular linked-list. You could probably do that with modulo division here.

Comment: you have a lot of errors in your code, please check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i prepared a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/k8g1mros/

logic behind this is:

```
var date = new Date();
var index = date.getDay();

function prev() {
  var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
  var nextIndex = index - 1 < 0 ? 6 : index-1;
  index = nextIndex
  console.log(nextIndex)
  document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = days[nextIndex];
}
document.getElementById("prev").addEventListener("click", function() {
  prev();
})
```

some explanation:

at first you get your actual day using `var index=date.getDay()`. By clicking `next` or `prev` this index will be count up / down. Once arrived at `0` (Sunday) or `6` (Saturday) the index will be reset to `0` / `6`.

This happens here (for prev):

```
var nextIndex = index - 1 < 0 ? 6 : index-1;
```

This is called `inline condition`. Further reading:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

[How to write an inline IF statement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270351/how-to-write-an-inline-if-statement-in-javascript)

This is an equivalent of:

```
var nextIndex = 0
if (index - 1 < 0 ) {
  nextIndex = 0
} else {
  nextIndex = index - 1
}
```

Do you understand the logic behind now?

Comment: Thanks for the help! It worked, but can you please explain some tings for me? I am bit unsure of what these statments do: 
         index = nextIndex
          document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = days[nextIndex];
 
and:

        console.log(nextIndex)

Comment: These two lines make it hard for me to understand it: var nextIndex = index - 1 < 0 ? 6 : index-1;
 and         console.log(nextIndex)

Comment: `var nextIndex = index - 1 < 0 ? 6 : index-1;` i explained this code line in my answer. You can read more about `inline conditions` in the links i posted in my answer. `console.log(nextIndex);` does nothing but logging `nextIndex`'s value to the console

Comment: you can also remove `console.log(nextIndex)` - this has no effect to your logic at all

Comment: @Alison if this answer help you out to resolve your issue, you should accept it.

Answer (score 2):

you would like to do something like this:

```js
var date = new Date();
var currentDay = date.getDay();
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = days[date.getDay()];

function next() {
  currentDay++;
  document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = days[currentDay];
}

function prev() {
  currentDay = currentDay - 1;
  document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = days[currentDay];

}
```

```html
<p>Click to change day</p>
<button type="button" name="btnPrev" onclick="next()"><</button>
<button type="button" name="btnNext" onclick="prev()">></button>
<p id="todayField"></p>
```

[please check](https://jsfiddle.net/L20s24dw/)

Comment: this results in undefined if you click `next` or `prev` for more than just one week

Comment: @messerbill true, but that was not the scope of the question

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you copy the same code in every function, you can refactor your code, with modulo division you can get the day:

```
var date = new Date();
var currentDay = date.getDay();
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday"];
document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = days[date.getDay()];


function next() {
    currentDay = ((currentDay+1) % 7);
    document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = days[currentDay];
}

function prev() {
    currentDay = ((currentDay-1) % 7);
    currentDay = (currentDay < 0) ? 6: currentDay;
    document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = days[currentDay];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When press the button get the weekday from your todayField, look for the index of this day in your days-array. Than add/subtract 1 for the next/previous day. Because the week has 7 days you need do this modulo 7 so you get a result between 0 and 6. If you subtract and the value is getting negative add 7 to it. Last update your field with this new weekday out of your weekday-array.

```
<body>
<p>Click to change day</p>
<button type="button" name="btnPrev" onclick="next()"><</button>
<button type="button" name="btnNext" onclick="prev()">></button>
<p id="todayField"></p>
<script>
    var date = new Date();
    var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
    document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = days[date.getDay()];

    function next() {
      var date = new Date();
      var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

      var actualDay = document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML;
      var dayNr =  days.indexOf(actualDay);
      dayNr = (dayNr - 1) %7;
      if (dayNr<0)
          dayNr += 7;
      document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = days[dayNr];
    }

    function prev() {
        var date = new Date();
        var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

        var actualDay = document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML;
        var dayNr =  days.indexOf(actualDay);
        dayNr = (dayNr + 1) %7;
        document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = days[dayNr];
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Beware**: you linked the "prev" function to "btnNext" button.
There is no need to rewrite the same code, so I cleared the `next()` and `prev()` functions.
The [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is what you're looking for.
In `prev()` you cannot use it since `-1 % 7` = `-1`, which would lead to `undefined`.

```
<body>
    <p>Click to change day</p>
    <button type="button" name="btnPrev" onclick="prev()">&lt;</button>
    <button type="button" name="btnNext" onclick="next()">&gt;</button>
    <p id="todayField"></p>
    <script>
    var date = new Date();
    var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
    var selectedDay = date.getDay();
    document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = days[selectedDay];

    function next() {
      selectedDay = (selectedDay + 1) % 7;
      document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = days[selectedDay];
    }

    function prev() {
      if (--selectedDay < 0)
        selectedDay = 6;
      document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = days[selectedDay];
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
var date = new Date();
var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
document.getElementById("todayField").innerHTML = days[date.getDay()];

$("button[name='btnNext']").click(function(){
    const displayedDay = $("#todayField").text();
    const dayIndex = days.indexOf(displayedDay);
  let newIndex;
  if(dayIndex < days.length - 1) {
    newIndex = dayIndex + 1;    
  } else {
    newIndex = 0;
  }
  let dayString = days[newIndex];
  $("p#todayField").empty().append(dayString);
});

$("button[name='btnPrev']").click(function(){
    const displayedDay = $("#todayField").text();
    const dayIndex = days.indexOf(displayedDay);
  let newIndex;
  if(dayIndex > 0) {
    newIndex = dayIndex - 1;    
  } else {
    newIndex = 6;
  }
  let dayString = days[newIndex];
  $("p#todayField").empty().append(dayString);
});
```