# SyntaxError Unexpected token if within a function

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, unexpected-token

I'm currently learning javascript (by using Google Script currently), I feel like this is a simple mistake, but I can't figure out a way around it.

The code below works, if I set "var colour" to a colour code. But when I change it to an if statement I get the issue. I've tried a bunch of different formats and continued having the same issue...

For info it just gets a few rows from a spreadsheet and then formats the selected rows and displays it to the user.

```
//Example of part of working code:
  if(Line.length == 0){
  var Line = lines 
  .slice(1)
  .filter(function(row) { return row[4] == e.message.text;})
  .map(function(row) {
    var colour = if(row[6]=1){return "#ff0000"};
    return '<b>' + row[3] + '</b> ('+ row[1] + ' or ' +row[2] + ')' + '\n' + '<font color=' + colour + '>Region: ' + row[6] + "</font>";
  });
  }
```

Comment: We can't tell you why an error occurs if you don't present the code where the error occurs. It's like going to the doctor, and saying "My right leg hurts; here's an X-ray of my healthy left leg so you can see how it should be." :) If you literally just inserted that `if` where the comment is, either move it to a new line, or add a semicolon after `"#000000"`.

Comment: I meant that if you replace the "#000000" with the comment (without the //) then you get an error. I've now changed what I wrote to be a bit clearer of the code that has an error...

Comment: See, I had no idea that's what you meant. It wouldn't have even crossed my mind. This is why seeing the code where the error happens is important. :) Thanks for the edit.

Comment: `var colour = if(row[6]=1){return "#ff0000"};` `var` expects an expression on the right-hand side, a statement is not allowed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write an inline IF statement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270351/how-to-write-an-inline-if-statement-in-javascript)

Comment: You cannot use an `if` in this place. If you want it inline, then use the conditional operator `? :` or alternatively convert to a proper `if` and assign the value in the blocks. Also note that `row[6]=1` [is assignment, not comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871616/in-javascript-vs/)

Comment: Thanks everyone! 
I actually did have (row[6] == 1) in my original code, I must have lost one when I tried to simplify the code to share here. Hopefully my next question here has a few less embarrassing mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between [statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements) and [expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators).

Just like you can put apples in a basket but not baskets in an apple, you can put expressions in a statement but not a statement in expressions.

`var colour = ...` is a statement that expects an expression on the right-hand side of the equals sign. You can't put an `if` statement there. You can use a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to make a a conditional expression:

```
var colour = row[6] == 1 ? "#ff0000" : "#000000";
```

Or you can use a full `if` statement to execute two variant assignment statements:

```
var colour;
if (row[6] == 1) {
  colour = "#ff0000";
} else {
  colour = "#000000";
}
```

Note also that `return #ff0000` would have returned literally `"#ff0000"`, not the text with the colour `#ff0000` as I assume you want; also note that `row[6] = 1` would *assign* `1` to `row[6]`, not compare it.

Comment: Thanks heaps! The difference is now quite obvious to me, I had never really had it explained to me like that. Cheers!