# If Else Statement for SearchParams [React Native]

Tags: typescript, react-native, searchbar

I am new to React Native and I am using typescript for React Native. Currently, I am having a difficulty to do if else statement for search function. Below is my code for if else statement for search function.

```
{searchParams !== "" (
  <View>
    <Text>Sorry, error occur</Text>
  </View>
  ) : (
  <View>
    <Text>Success!</Text>
  </View>
)}
```

Comment: what is the error youre getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{searchParams !== "" ? (
  <View>
    <Text>Sorry, error occur</Text>
  </View>
  ) : (
  <View>
    <Text>Success!</Text>
  </View>
)}
```

You're missing a question mark: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10270383/11760094

Comment: Thank you so much. My if else statement for search function work after I added question mark

Answer (score 0):

```
{searchParams !== "" ?
  <View>
    <Text>Sorry, error occur</Text>
  </View>
   : 
  <View>
    <Text>Success!</Text>
  </View>
}
```

here is the link 
[if-else statement inside jsx: ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44046037/if-else-statement-inside-jsx-reactjs)

Comment: Thank you so much. My if else statement for search function work after I added question mark