# passing className from the function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of items and I want to change the background of some of the items.

Checking via the bool you are gonna see that part in switch.
`className={classes.Items}` this is working but how can I pass `className` here?

```js
const createClassName = (data) => {
    const className = "Items";
    switch (data.isRead){
        case false:
            return className + "Unread";
        case true:
            return className ;
    }
};

{props.data.map((item) => (
    <MenuItem
    // className={classes.Items}
    //className={createClassNameForNotificationNeededRow(item)}
    key={item.key}
>
```

Comment: Couple of points worth noting: It's excessive to use a `switch` for a boolean comparison (That could just be an `if(){}else{}` or even `return data.isRead ? className : className + "Unread"`) Also, your `className + "Unread"` will not have a space between, so the result will be a single "ItemsUnread" class (Which may or may not be intentioal)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I remove the unnecessary parts so this is not the original code. But stuck at the other part!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you use module style files to load classes and then you want to to conditionally apply them, in this case your data is a boolean, either `true` or `false`, and remember that classes you read from the imported style modules will be changed by some plugins before they make their way to browser to make it a unique className like `items_knc5d5sx` so keep in mind to use `classes.someClassName` instead using a string, anyway, here is a small suggestion for your use case:

```js
const createClassName = (classes, data) => {
        return `${classes.items} ${!data.isRead ? classes.Unread : ""}`
};
```

Then use this function **createClassName** when you render to create the classes for each item dynamically.

```
{props.data.map((item) => (     
    <MenuItem
      className={createClassName(classes, item)}
      key={item.key}
    >
}
```

Comment: const createClassName = (data) => {
        return `${classes.NotificationItems} ${data.isRead ? classes.NotificationItemsUnread : ""}`;
    };

combined both answers and solved with this, thanks!

Comment: Also not that I mistakenly wrote the condition, when `data.isRead` is `false` you apply _unread_ styles, otherwise it'll be `items` only, so the right condition depending on the code in the question is:
```jsx
return `${classes.items} ${!data.isRead ? classes.Unread : ""}
```

Glad you solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69210373/passing-classname-from-the-function-in-react#comment122326366_69210373), no need for that `switch`, I've changed it to an [inline `if`-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270351/how-to-write-an-inline-if-statement-in-javascript).

---

To get the desired behaviour, call the `createClassName` function on each `map()` iteration.

Example snippet:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {

    // Function to create item className
    createClassName = (data) => {
        return (data.isRead) ? 'ItemsUnread' : 'Items';
    };
    
    // Debug test data
    testData = [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3, isRead: true } ];
      
    // Render
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.testData.map((data) => {
                    const className = this.createClassName(data);
                    const content = `${data.id}: ${className}`;
                    return <div className={className}>{content}</div>
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.body);
```

```css
.Items { color: green; }
.ItemsUnread { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: const createClassName = (data) => {
        return `${classes.NotificationItems} ${data.isRead ? classes.NotificationItemsUnread : ""}`;
    };

combined both answers and solved with this, thanks!

Comment: I always upvoting and giving people credit. I accepted other answer cuz its more useful to my case. Thanks a lot for detailing the question and giving detail answer!