# Passing BEM className in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

In the example below, how can I use the `Post` component in such a way that new posts and old posts have their own unique classes that follow [BEM recommendations](http://getbem.com/introduction/).

1. Every element needs it's own unique className
2. Cascading dependencies (`.posts-new post` or `.posts-old post`) should be avoided
3. Each component defines a new Block on its outermost element

What I want is for the `className` to reflect new vs. old. Ideally, `post-new` and `post-old`.

One approach I've considered is to pass "new" or "old" via a props attribute (`type="old"`, for example) to the Post component and then dynamically create the className ([this post leverages such an approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69210373/passing-classname-from-the-function-in-react)). Is that the recommended approach for such a situation or is there another technique I'm not seeing?

```
// Display new posts
Posts className="posts-new"
  Post className="?"

// Display old posts
Posts className="posts-old"
  Post className="?"
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I chose to use an attribute to pass "new" and "old" from the Posts component to the Post component.

```
<Posts type="new" />
<Posts type="old" />
```

Then, in the Post component I was able to add this to the className of my article tag via a template literal.

```
<article className={`post post-${props.type}`}>
```

From the feedback I've received from other devs, this is an acceptable approach.