# Why if-else is not working in this react code, cause I am not getting output?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was trying to achieve something like this in react
e.g. user enter his/her age and when click the button following logic should work

if age>18 then Eligible for Passport
else Not eligible

But I am getting no output when I enter the age and click the Enter button.

```
import { useState } from "react";



function App() 
{
    const[age,`your text`setAge]=useState(0)
    const handleInput= (event)=>{setAge(event.target.value)}

    const Checker = ()=>{
    if(age>18){
      return <h1>Eligible for Cnic</h1>
    }else{
      return <h1>Not-Eligible for Cnic</h1>
    }
    }
  
    return (
    <div className="App">
    <input type="text" onChange={handleInput}/>
    <button onClick={()=><Checker/>}>Check</button>
    {/* <Checker/> */}
    </div>
  );
}
``your text``
export default App;
```

This code is showing no output when button click is used but without button click it shows the output

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: `\`your text\`setAge` ??

Comment: ?? `onClick={()=><Checker/>}`

Comment: Why is your `checker` returning JSX instead of calling a setState for a variable that  you then use in your actual return?

Comment: Actually I want an input field and a submit button, when user input his age then he/she click on button 
after then the output is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost certainly want a second state variable here, and then use that as part of your normal render.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() 
{
    const [age, setAge] = useState(0);
    const [verified, setVerified] = useState(false);

    const handleInput = ({ target }) => setAge(target.value);
    const verifyAge = () => setVerified(age > 18);
  
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input type="text" onChange={handleInput} placeholder="Your age"/>
        <button onClick={verifyAge}>Check</button>
        <p>{verified? `` : `Not-`}Eligible for Cnic</p>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I wanted for practice as a beginner, Your logic is Great. God Bless you

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a DOM element from an `onChange` event, nothing will be done with the returned value.

---

There are much better ways of doing this.

As requested by OP in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75558723/why-if-else-is-not-working-in-this-react-code-cause-i-am-not-getting-output/75558797?noredirect=1#comment133308021_75558797), I've

- Added a `result` `useState` where we save the string you want to show

  ```js
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);
  ```
- On button click, call `onButtonClick` that will use the `setResult` hook to save the `result` with you `if` statement, that I've changed to an [inline variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270351/how-to-write-an-inline-if-statement-in-javascript)

  ```js
  const onButtonClick = () => 
      setResult((age > 18) 
          ? 'Eligible for Cnic' 
          : 'Not-Eligible for Cnic');
  ```
- If `result` is a true value, show `result` wrapped in `h1`

  ```
  {result && <h1>{result}</h1>}
  ```

---

###### Updated snippet:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {

    const [age, setAge] = useState(0);
    const [result, setResult] = useState(null);

    const handleInput = (event) => setAge(event.target.value);
    
    const onButtonClick = () => 
        setResult((age > 18) 
            ? 'Eligible for Cnic' 
            : 'Not-Eligible for Cnic');
    
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <input type="text" onChange={handleInput} />
            <button onClick={onButtonClick}>{'Check'}</button>
            {result && <h1>{result}</h1>}
        </div>
    );
}
  
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I would probably lower-case `Checker` to distinguish it from a component.

Comment: Thanks you for your response but the problem is still there I don't want to change state run time entering the age and the output is there, e.g in the above code 
Can you add a submit button, when user add age then click on button then the output is shown

Comment: you really just want a second useState here, though.

Comment: Not my favorite way of doing this, but I've update my answer with your idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [age, setAge] = useState();
  const [verified, setVerified] = useState(false);
  const [btnClick, setBtnClick] = useState(false);
  const handleVerify = () => {
    setVerified(age > 18);
    setBtnClick(true);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter Your Age"
        onChange={(event) => setAge(event.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={handleVerify}>Verify</button>
      <br />
      {btnClick ? <p>{verified ? `` : `Not `}Verified</p> : ``}
    </div>
  );
}
```