# Cannot conditionnaly insert a wrapper tag in a React component

Tags: reactjs

The following code is raising an error:

```
{index % 2 === 0 && <div className='my-class'>}
```

> Unexpected token, expected "," (9:14)

---

```
import AnotherComponent  from './Anothercomponent.jsx'

export default function CurrentComponent({ datas, onChangeValue }) {
  
  return (
    <section>
      {datas.map((data, index) => (
        {index % 2 === 0 && <div className='my-wrapper'>}
        <AnotherComponent/>
        {index % 2 === 0 && </div>}
      ))}
    </section>
  );
}
```

the goal is to get this result:

```
<section>
  <div class="my-class">
    <AnotherComponent/>
    <AnotherComponent/>
  </div>
  <div class="my-class">
    <AnotherComponent/>
    <AnotherComponent/>
  </div>
</section>
```

Could you help please?

Comment: Seems like you're taking an awkward approach to simply applying the _class_ conditionally. Do you actually need the div element to not be present in some cases?

Answer (score 2):

You can't render a open and close element like that with a condition.

First of all, the `return` of a `map` can only return a single DOM element, so you'll need to wrap it in a div, or React.Fragment.

But you still need to change the way you wrap it in a div.

Consider the following were we use an [inline if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270351/how-to-write-an-inline-if-statement-in-javascript) to choose between

- Wrapping `<AnotherComponent/>` in a `<div>`
- Just render `<AnotherComponent/>` without a parent

```
export default function CurrentComponent({ datas, onChangeValue }) {
    return (
        <section>
            {datas.map((data, index) => (
                {
                    (index % 2 === 0)
                        ? <div className='my-wrapper'><AnotherComponent/></div>
                        : <AnotherComponent/>
                }
            ))}
        </section>
    );
}
```

---

You could also define a Wrapper component that will be the div or an empty Fragment:

```
return (
    <section>
        {datas.map((data, index) => {
            const Wrapper = (index % 2 === 0) ? 'div' : React.Fragment;
            return (
                <Wrapper>
                    <AnotherComponent/>
                </Wrapper>
            )
        }}
    </section>
);
```

---

A small demo showing the second example in a runnable react snippet:

```js
const Example = () => {
  
    {/* Render <Foo /> 20 times */}
    return [...Array(20)].map((e, i) => <Foo index={i} />);
}

// Foo is rendered without a parent, unless (index % 2 === 0), then Foo is wrapped in a <em>
// <em> is styled with lightblue text
const Foo = ({ index }) => {

    const Wrapper = (index % 2 === 0) ? 'em' : React.Fragment;
    
    return <Wrapper>{`Index --> ${index}`}</Wrapper>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
div { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
em { color: lightblue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @Ostone0 thanks for your quick reply.  I learn something with your second solution.
Unfortunatly I guess my question was badly formulated. I need to have  <AnotherComponent/> inserted into the wrapper when the condition is false. Then I need an open tag...
So I guess I have to look on the css way of styling instead.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'open tag'. Maybe add a [mre] to your question?

Comment: I added a example snippet, hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: Yes I see your point Ostone0. Guess the simplest way is to refactor the css instead of smashing my head with the code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure what CSS has to do with this haha, but Glad my answer helped ;) Please consider upvoting / accepting it for further readers.

Answer (score 1):

In JSX, a conditional rendering is applicable on an `Element` and not with a single element tag.

```
<>
{
    (index % 2 === 0) ? (
          <div className='my-class'>
          ...
          </div>
          : <AnotherComponent />
    )
}
</>
```

Comment: Yes I understood that was my error :-)

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, the issue is you can't render a partial element.

```js
{index % 2 === 0 && <div className='my-wrapper'>}
```

will cause an error because the `div` element has no closing tag, react needs the entire component in a single expression.

For your case, you can do something like this

```js
import AnotherComponent  from './Anothercomponent.jsx'

function renderMapItem(data, index) {
  // ideally this would be a unique value from the data
  // something like data.id, we can use index for now
  const key = index;

  if (index % 2 === 0) {
    return (
      <div className='my-wrapper' key={key}>
        <AnotherComponent/>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <AnotherComponent key={key}/>;
}

export default function CurrentComponent({ datas, onChangeValue }) {
  return (
    <section>
      {datas.map(renderMapItem)}
    </section>
  );
}
```